# SwiftUI Combine cannot convert type

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I don't understand why I have error:

> Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type 'AnyPublisher<[Comments], Never>'

```
func fetchCommetsPublisher(endpoint: EndPoint) -> AnyPublisher<[Comments], Never> {
     URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: stringUrl(with: endpoint)!)
        .map{$0.data}
        .decode(type: [Comments].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .replaceError(with: [])
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        .assign(to: \.isFormValid, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancel)
```

```
struct Comments: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var postId: Int
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var email: String
    var body: String
}
```

Comment: How do you intend to use `fetchCommetsPublisher`?

Comment: List, .onAppear { my class.fuction}

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return publisher from this function you have to stop at eraser, like

```
func fetchCommetsPublisher(endpoint: EndPoint) -> AnyPublisher<[Comments], Never> {
     URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: stringUrl(with: endpoint)!)
        .map{$0.data}
        .decode(type: [Comments].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .replaceError(with: [])
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()        // << this returns AnyPublisher<[Comments], Never>
}
```

Comment: I remove .eraseToAnyPublisher() and now I have other error

Comment: As per Asperi, you need to remove --- .assign(to: \.isFormValid, on: self) .store(in: &cancel). Need to keep last statement as .eraseToAnyPublisher()